# Java installation issue in Fedora 27

Tags: java, fedora

I'm trying to install Java in Fedora 27. I have downloaded and tried to install this. But I'm getting an error like this: "package jdk-11.0.1-2000:11.0.1-ga.x86_64 does not have a compatible architecture". I have tried all versions given. But no solution. Any Ideas please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good.
I had the same problem in fedora 29.
I solved it with this.

sudo su

rpm -Uvh jdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.rpm

alternatives --config java